# How to divide image into block and add zero border for each block

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, block

I've a problem I need to divide image into blocks and add zero border for each blocks, one or two zeros is enough, I added border for all image but I want to add border for each block of image.

note::: no of block any size for ex: 4X4 blocks

```
img=round(100*rand(4,4));
[n,m]=size(img);
x=zeros(n+2,m+2);
%%%%%Applying zero padding to the image
for i=1:n+2
    for j=1:m+2
        if i==1 || i==n+2 || j==1 || j==m+2
            x(i,j)=0;
        else
            x(i,j)=img(i-1,j-1);
        end
    end
end
x
```

I need to get output like this around each block one or two zero

```
 0     0     0     0    0    0     0   0  
 0    84    80     0    0   65    85   0
 0    29    19     0    0   23    77   0
 0     0     0     0    0    0     0   0
 0     0     0     0    0    0     0   0
 0    84    80     0    0   66    74   0
 0    29    19     0    0   36    80   0
 0     0     0     0    0    0     0   0
```

Comment: I have no idea why you deleted and reposted the question. Please make clear how the expected output should look like.

Again: Should the second line look like `0xx0xx0` or `0xx00xx0`? Borders around does not make clear if there should be a single separator or two in between.

Comment: I deleted and add cause I tried to edit it after delete & add I see edit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%n: Size of original matrix
n=size(img,1)
%prealloc new matrix
img2=zeros(n+3,n+3)
%p indicates indices to store img at
p=[(2:n/2+1),(n/2+3:n+2)]
%Copy img to the correct positions
img2(p,p)=img
```

Comment: thanks dear Daniel for your help exactly I need this thanks again

Comment: is correct but, what happen if I change size of image to 256x256 ?

Comment: With the correction of Luis Mendo the code works for every even size (2x2, 4x4, 6x6....)